# Cannot call method 'begin' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tools

Hello i have this script working fine here.. know it has no syntax errors or else.

http://jsfiddle.net/xHL35/9/

The problem is when i try to implement it here..

I have tried to unset the jquery.min.js cause thats the only file i see that my cause conflict, not twitter or facebook js, and just for test i just test it and I always get

Cannot call method 'begin' of undefined

Heres the link so you can check it

http://queretaro.orsilin.com.mx/index.php?page=item/view/15/Probando

this is the part causing conflict

```
if (nextImageIndex === 0) {
            scrollapi.begin(200);
        } else if ( nextImageIndex % 4 === 0 && nextImageIndex > 0) {
            scrollapi.next(200);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Learn to debug!

So that means `scrollapi` is undefined. look where it is defined.

```
var scrollapi = $(".scrollable").data('scrollable');
console.log($(".scrollable").length);  // Says it is Zero...sooo hence your problem
console.log($(".scrollable").data('scrollable'));  //undefined
```

So what is the problem? You have no element on the page when this code runs that has the class `.scrollable`.

Comment: Really appreciate!!! But the error was about "next", where do you see that .scrollable was not defined??? pls let me know

I always want lo learn to debug, do you have a link, im not lazy love to read (sorry about my english by the way)

Comment: I walked up the chain to find the problem. So the error said that scrollapi was undefined so I looked to see where it was defined. I set a break point in the JavaScript debugger and saw that it did not find the element. Ctrl-F on the source showed that there was no element on the page with that class. Simple. ;)

Comment: And awesome someone downvoted my correct answer. I love those people!

Comment: you have to be more of 125 pts to downvote..  i will upvote you everywhere XD!!

Comment: Sorry i really try to debug but this one dont even send an error. Why my counter is not counting from 0.. well its weird i try to debug or see whats going on, i really look inside .items, but i think is somthing else :(